# Highcharts - Toggling the lines that run parallel to X axis for each value on Y axis?

Tags: highcharts, linechart

How you toggle the lines that are parallel to X axis and appear for each value on Y axis? 
These ones - [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its the `yAxis.gridWidth` - look the [API Doc](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.gridLineWidth)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tezLvap5/)

Answer (score 2):

```
xAxis: {
 ...  
 lineWidth: 0,
 minorGridLineWidth: 0,
 lineColor: 'transparent',
 ...          
 labels: {
   enabled: false
 },
 minorTickLength: 0,
 tickLength: 0
}
```

Just add this to the x axis definition